# Acabar saliéndose algo

Tags: significado-en-contexto

I'm reading the following article: https://sputniknews.lat/20230122/occidente-penso-que-iba-a-ser-muy-facil-derrotar-a-rusia-a-traves-ucrania-1134904554.html

At one point, it says:

"Siempre les ha pasado esto [subestimar a Rusia]. Desde que Hitler invadió la Unión Soviética, nunca han calculado bien la capacidad que tiene Rusia de responder a las guerras. Por muy mal que se encuentre su economía, como ocurrió en la Primera Guerra Mundial, que acabó saliéndose, provocando que Estados Unidos tuviera que entrar con Woodrow Wilson. [En ese momento también] desestimaron el potencial ruso. No ven el desarrollo de esta nación, que además es una nación que tiene muchas materias primas necesarias para su desarrollo", sostiene la autora de libros como El regreso de la geopolítica. Rusia y la reconfiguración del poder mundial (2016).

Maybe they meant to say, *de la* que acabó saliéndose? It makes no sense to me, I don't understand what they mean by saliéndose in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the meaning here is definition 40 of salir in the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/salir?m=form).

> 40. prnl. En algunos juegos, hacer los tantos o las jugadas necesarios para ganar.

So the reference is to the fact that they were on the winning side in the 14-18 War. Obviously this is a figurative use as that war was hardly a game for the soldiers and inhabitants of the lands where it was fought.

Answer (score 1):

"*Por muy mal que se encuentre su economía, como ocurrió en la Primera Guerra Mundial, **que acabó saliéndose**, provocando que Estados Unidos tuviera que entrar con Woodrow Wilson*".

Entiendo que estas son unas declaraciones realizadas por Ana Teresa Gutiérrez del Cid, analista geopolítica de la Universidad Autónoma Metropolitana de México, por lo que en el lenguaje es oral, y posteriormente transcrito como artículo.

En un lenguaje oral, muchas veces se sobrentienden aspectos que no figuran en él de forma directa o apropiada por lo que hay que trascribirlo para darle cierta orientación. De hecho, las frases entre corchetes lo que hacen es hacer entender algo que oralmente no se ha comentado, añadiendo cierto contexto.

Aunque legible y comprensible la frase , **que acabó saliéndose**, no deja de ser una oración pobre, ya que aparece aparentemente indeterminada y con una redacción deficiente para ser leída.

Mejor hubiera sido, entre otras fórmulas decir:

- *como ocurrió en la Primera Guerra Mundial*, **de la que Rusia acabó saliendo**, provocando...
- *como ocurrió en la Primera Guerra Mundial*, **de la que acabó saliéndose**, provocando...
- como ocurrió en la Primera Guerra Mundial, **de la que Rusia acabó saliéndose**, provocando...

Así pues, estamos simplemente ante una deficiente redacción tanto de la persona que lo dijo oralmente como del periodista que no repasó bien la trascripción, pudiendo dar lugar a malentendidos.

---

**I don't understand what they mean by saliéndose in this context.**

*No entiendo qué quieren decir con saliéndose en este contexto.*

"*Por muy mal que se encuentre su economía, como ocurrió en la Primera Guerra Mundial, **Rusia acabó saliendo de la guerra**, provocando...

Se refiere a que Rusia acabó por salirse de la guerra o contienda, lo que provocó que los EEUU intervinieran, ya que los Estados Centrales (Alemania y Austria-Hungría) tendrían ahora un frente menos que defender y podrían concentrar sus tropas de manera más eficiente.

Comment: "de la que (Rusia) acabó saliéndose de ella" is ungrammatical, because you are repeating the prepositional phrase, as if you said: "guerra de la que Rusia acabó saliéndose de la guerra".

Comment: @Gustavson ¡Gracias por la corrección!

Answer (score 1):

The relative clause in the sentence below (there should be a comma or a dash, not a period, before "por muy mal ...":

- Desde que Hitler invadió la Unión Soviética, nunca han calculado bien la capacidad que tiene Rusia de responder a las guerras. Por muy mal que se encuentre su economía, como ocurrió en la Primera Guerra Mundial, que acabó saliéndose, provocando que Estados Unidos tuviera que entrar con Woodrow Wilson.

is ungrammatical, because, as used, "salirse" is a prepositional verb (salirse **de** algo = abandon sth).

The revision proposed by OP is required to render the sentence grammatical:

- Desde que Hitler invadió la Unión Soviética, nunca han calculado bien la capacidad que tiene Rusia de responder a las guerras, por muy mal que se encuentre su economía, como ocurrió en la Primera Guerra Mundial, **de la** que acabó saliéndose, provocando que Estados Unidos tuviera que entrar con Woodrow Wilson.